# .net BitArray.Get performance issue

Tags: c#, .net, performance, entity-framework-6, bitarray

I have an asp.net application and trying to optimize it performance. I find one issue with **BitArray.Get** method **performance**. It's execution time differs **from 100 to 250ms**. It's defiantly too much. This method called inside IEnumerable.FirstOrDefault. Is there any idea why this happening and how to optimize it?

[image]

UPD

This method call appears during EF materialization. one more example from same trace:
[image]

There are also other examples with method processing duration just 1ms.

Comment: Both calls in this tree are impossible. Where is this data from?

Comment: Are you optimizing on your 0,01% of your overall applications CPU consumption? There should be bigger fishes to catch first.

Comment: It would be useful to see the context. Please show us your code. Maybe someone can optimize it. Is 252ms the time for calling it 1,158,375 times?

Comment: @usr it profiling result from just trace

Comment: @AloisKraus I found other fish and I know how to deal with that. unfortunately this one method appears to often in profiling snapshot and takes too much time

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I'm not sure is it correct to share code of private project. I found lots of this method calls inside EF matearilizations of IQueryable. 252ms is for exactly this one call. Other could take 1ms, or 500ms. I'll attach one more example

Comment: The new call tree is impossible as well. BitArray.GetBit does not set Length. What data is this?

Comment: @usr I changed second picture. Length setter is open. For my surprise setter for BitArray.Length exist: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.length. This data is taken by Telerik JustTrace from .net web app. This is EF materialization

Comment: EF6 infrastructure is using heavily `BitArray`s (I guess instead of `bool[]`), so there is nothing you can do to "optimize" your app (except not using EF:). The `Get` method itself is fast enough, I guess it's just called too many times, and if they used `bool[]` then you would see similar report, bot for bool array. Forget it, this is not your fish :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the data.

In your second picture `BitArray.Get()` takes about the 3 times as long compared to the first picture and the number of calls is about 3 times as high as well (~3.1mio compared to ~1.2mio). Therefore I conclude that the time in ms reflects these millions of calls, not just one call! In both cases the time per call is around ~200ns per call (218 and 201 ns). There is just a difference of 8.4 percent. This is pretty consistent.

`BitArray.Get()` is ~ 1 mio times faster than you thought!